# Warnings in health reports - How to solve them?

Tags: sharepoint-server

1. More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered with SharePoint
2. Distributed cache service is not enabled in this deployment
3. This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems
4. The Security Token Service is not available.
   failing Service : SPTimerService

And one more problem is I can't find Analytics_GUID folder at :
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you DC is not properly configured. I would say re configured it as the instruction [in this technet.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613%28v=office.15%29.aspx#repair)

Here are indviual solutions from MSFT for all 4 issues.

1: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891120(v=office.15).aspx

3:  http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=Distributed+cache+service+is+not+enabled+in+this+deployment&d=4727596378817451&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=85U6_jbd1gJl3N-2HBuhDJ3W6HyRPX6I

3: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891108(v=office.15).aspx

4: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh564112(v=office.14).aspx